# Nestjs logger timezone: how to set it?

Tags: logging, timezone, nestjs

we are logging in nestjs like this:

```
private readonly logger = new Logger(MyNiceService.name);
....
this.logger.log(`Log somthing`, args);
```

This works but the timestamp that the Logger applies is one hour off (the local time in Amsterdam).

How can i persuade the Logger to use my local timezone?

E.G.: i have set my TZ variable via the .env but the Logger nicely ignores this.